# Can i use a partial view inside a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Im using a partial view, and i have some Razor code that will be used a lot of times in the partial view... Can i use partial views inside this partial view?

Or have a better way to do this?

When i try to do this:

this is the principal page:

```
@model List<GolTripulacao.WebApi.Areas.LOG.Controllers.HomeController.Campo>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Relatorio";
}


<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" id="" name="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div>
                    @Html.Partial("~/Areas/LOG/Views/Home/PhonePreview.cshtml", Model)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

who uses a partial view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;font-size:20px;overflow:auto;">        

        @if (Model != null)
        {
            <div class="container" style="background-color:orangered;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        @ViewBag.Relatorio
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            foreach (var campo in Model)
            {
                if (campo.Tipo == "Text")
                {
                    @Html.Partial("~/Areas/LOG/Views/Home/text.cshtml", campo)
                }        

            }
        }

    </div>

</div>


<style>

    input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        display: none;
    }

</style>
```

and this partial calls this another partial

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @model.Name:
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8" style="text-align:right;">
            <input type="text" style="width:100%;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

gives me an error:

```
'HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'RenderPartial' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax
```

regards!!

Rafael

Comment: Yes ! You can. Share the relevant code how are you trying it so that we can help with your error

Comment: ok!! ive updated the question

Comment: Where are you calling the other partial ? Currently you are calling one partial in your main view inside a loop. Also your partial should be strongly typed to the type you are passing to it. The line `model.Name` should throw you an error. Where are you making the RenderPartial call BTW ?

Comment: sorry shiu, i forgot to put the principal page...There are 3 pages..1 principal and  2 partials

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that error because your partial views are not strongly typed.

You need to make them strongly typed to the data you are passing in.

You are passing the Model of your principal page to the first partial view. Your Model is a list of `Campo`. So your first partial view should also be strongly typed to that type (`List<Campo>`).

Add this line as the first line in your first partial view (`PhonePreview.cshtml`)

```
@model List<GolTripulacao.WebApi.Areas.LOG.Controllers.HomeController.Campo>
```

Inside your `PhonePreview.cshtml` partial view, you are looping through the items passed to it and calling the `text.cshtml` partial view when your if condition returns true. Here you are passing a simple `Campo` object to the text partial view. So it should be strongly typed to `Campo` type.

Add this line as the first line in your first partial view (`text.cshtml`)

```
@model GolTripulacao.WebApi.Areas.LOG.Controllers.HomeController.Campo
```

. Also you should be accessing the Name property like `Model.Name` , not `model.Name`

```
@model GolTripulacao.WebApi.Areas.LOG.Controllers.HomeController.Campo
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        @Model.Name
    </div>
```

Comment: ive tryed and gives me an error when i execute: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'GolTripulacao.WebApi.Areas.LOG.Controllers.HomeController+Campo', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GolTripulacao.WebApi.Areas.LOG.Controllers.HomeController+Campo]'.

Comment: Looks like you swapped the order. Your `PhonePreview` should be strongly typed to the `List<Campo>` and `text.cshtml` should be strongly typed to `Campo`

Comment: ah sorry Shyju my mistake! It worked!!! Thanks so much for your time..You´re the best!

Comment: You are welcome! Glad i could help. BTW, There is a **Y** in the middle